# Как запустить docker nginx на ubuntu server 16?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

Есть у меня связка docker контейнеров nginx/php-fpm/mysql. Запускаются и управляются они через docker-compose. Через volume я монтирую туда свое приложение. И есть ubuntu server c настроенным доменом.

Как мне сделать так что бы запросы на сервер попадали в контейнер с nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо для вашего nginx-сервиса задать значение параметру `ports`

```
version: 3.1
services:
    ...
    nginx:
        ...
        ports:
          - "444:443"
```

для того чтобы открыть nginx для доступа по HTTPS или `"80:80"` для HTTP